# Why does the mean method does not work correctly?

Tags: java, static, inner-classes

I have the following class `imp` with inner class `ScoringSummaryImplementation`, when I tested the `mean()` method alone it works correctly, but when I test it as I show in the main method the answer goes incorrectly, I need to know the reason:

```
public class imp implements Normalizer {
     public static List<BigDecimal> dataToBeNormalized = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public ScoringSummary zscore(Path csvPath, Path destPath, String colToStandardize) {

        ScoringSummary scoringObejct = new ScoringSummaryImplementation();
        if (!Files.exists(csvPath)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("source file not found");
        }

        try {
            readDataToBeNormalized(csvPath, destPath, colToStandardize);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(imp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (CsvValidationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(imp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //Z-score
        for (int i = 0; i < dataToBeNormalized.size(); i++) {
            BigDecimal sub = (dataToBeNormalized.get(i).subtract(scoringObejct.mean()));
            try {
                BigDecimal divide = sub.divide(scoringObejct.standardDeviation(), 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
                dataToBeNormalized.set(i, divide);
            } catch (ArithmeticException e) {

            }

        }

        return scoringObejct;
    }

    

    private void readDataToBeNormalized(Path csvPath, Path destPath, String colToStandardize) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, CsvValidationException {
        int indexOfTheCol = -1;

        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvPath.toString()));
        String[] header = reader.readNext();
        for (int i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
            if (header[i].equalsIgnoreCase(colToStandardize)) {
                indexOfTheCol = i;
            }
        }
        if (indexOfTheCol == -1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("column " + colToStandardize + " not found");
        }
        String[] values;
        while ((values = reader.readNext()) != null) {
            dataToBeNormalized.add(new BigDecimal(values[indexOfTheCol]));

        }

    }

    //Inner class to implement ScoringSummary
    public static class ScoringSummaryImplementation implements ScoringSummary {
        
    
        @Override
        public BigDecimal mean() {
             BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal("0");
            BigDecimal sizeOfTheList = new BigDecimal(dataToBeNormalized.size());
            for (int i = 0; i < dataToBeNormalized.size(); i++) {
                sum = sum.add(dataToBeNormalized.get(i));
            }

         sum.divide(sizeOfTheList, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
           
           return sum.divide(sizeOfTheList, 2, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN);
        }

    }
    
}
```

// test in the main:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\GitHub\\J2EE\\demo\\src\\main\\java\\com\\mycompany\\demo\\d.csv");
        Path p2 = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\DELL\\Documents\\GitHub\\J2EE\\demo\\src\\main\\java\\com\\mycompany\\demo\\des.csv");
        
    Normalizer n1 = new imp ();
   
    ScoringSummary n2 = n1.zscore(p, p2, "age");
    
    
        BigDecimal mean = n2.mean();
        System.out.println(mean);
    }
    
}
```

Here is output:

```
0.82
```

Here is age column:

### |age |

|5434|
|42423|
|54534|
|3333|

Comment: Have you tried printing the content of `dataToBeNormalized`?

Comment: yes! it works correctly too. @Andreas

Comment: Then **debug** your code. Step through the execution of `mean()` to see what's going on.

Comment: if you're trying to write unit tests, you shouldn't have a main method in there

Comment: A couple of remarks: 1) you should step through your code with a debugger and see what happens to your data, 2) in `zscore(...)` you read the data, calculate the mean etc. and call `dataToBeNormalized.set(i, divide);` (presumably to normalize it). Hence the mean of the data will then be different because when you call `mean()` again the values will be different, 3) you should consider using enhanced for, e.g. `for (BigDecimal value :  dataToBeNormalized) { sum = sum.add(value); }` and 4) your code is formatted awkwardly, making it hard to read.

Comment: It won't help to ignore exceptions as you do in your Z score routine. You'll get an 'invisible' error if an exception is thrown.